# How many non visual symbols present in String

Tags: java, string, character, apache-poi

I was doing parsing of an excel document using POI API.
Since some of the cells contains line break(`\n` or `BR`) at the end, I have to remove those characters before processing (eg: I'm working on URLs on that excel document and calling that URL in my program using another  API.)

Now I want to know how many non visual symbols are present in the string returned by the excel parsed string and what are they ?
How a java code can be written for accomplishing this task ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What [research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/616460) have you done?

Comment: Define "non visual symbols"

Comment: Iterate through the characters of the string, and if the current char is "non visual", then increment a counter. The hard part is to define what "non visual" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are taking  tab spaces , form feed , new line , white spaces as non visual characters well they are called non graphic symbols in most of the languages and are represented in ASCII from 0 to 32 (in decimal form)

The following link will tell you what ASCII codes are doing and their corresponding code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t(v=vs.80).aspx

```
    String str="default string";
    Integer ctr[] = new Integer[32];
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        ctr[i] = new Integer(0);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<str.length() ;i++){

        switch(str.charAt(i)){

        case 0 :
                ctr[0]++;
                break;
        case 1: ctr[1]++;
            break;

        case 2:
                ctr[2]++;
                break;

            //remaining counter 
        case 32:
                ctr[32]++;
                break;
        }
    }
```

you can use ctr[] for checking counter values